# Is asking questions here, in order to gain insight for product development ok?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Essentially I'm trying to gain insight around something as I'm developing a product/service in this area. I need to ask questions around the topic and potentially speak to potential users of the product/service.

My question is - is it ok to discuss this type of thing here, or is there somewhere else that would be better suited?

I am deliberately omitting any reference to the product/service that I'm working on, as this isn't some marketing ploy, and I'd really appreciate some guidance around this type of thing.

Thanks

Matt

Comment: There's always the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22/show-me-the-money), where we encourage open-ended discussions to take place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past questions on products / services or applications were considered offtopic and were closed.

If the questions are around generic understanding of say how a specific feature of something [say for example how are trades matched in exchange] if worded right would be on topic and welcome.

Question around how should I develop a particular feature and whether there is a market [say for example if I create a mobile app to do XYZ, or new app that gives analysis of stocks and preffered buys based on ABC criteria] and which one is better is considered off topic.

Comment: Thanks for this, it really helps. Are open ended questions permitted, for example - "What problems do people find when xyz"?

Comment: Not really, survey or opinion-based questions tend to be off-topic. Although, it really depends on the question and how it's phrased. @littleadv recent answer on 401k vs transfer to IRA was dead-on, yet the question bordered on just what I'd warn against. So it's really a grey area.